# misunderstanding of the logic of if/else if conditionals

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I can't quite grasp the if/else conditionals. would anyone be able to explain the logic/reasoning to why it works and why it doesn't work? Using p5.js I am aiming to simply move circles across the screen and back again but I can't get it to carry out the second else if conditional.

---

I have tried making the conditional as width but i figure that wouldn't work as it would get stuck. the issue i think is more with the second conditional as the first conditional works the same with the second removed.

---

```js
var circlex = 18;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  //background(255);
  framerate = 10;
  //noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  strokeWeight(10);
  //stroke(random(255));
  // for (var circleX = 20; circleX < width; circleX += 40) {
  //fill ((0), random(255), random(255));

  ellipse(circlex, 200, 25, 25);
  if (circlex < 250) {
    circlex = circlex + 50;
  } else if (circlex > 390) {
    circlex = circlex - 50;
  }
}
```

essentially this runs the first if coniditonal but the ellipse stops at 250 and doesn't move any more, haven't managed to make it go the other way at all. i think this is due to a lack of knowledge and understanding on my part so if anyone would be able to explain what breaks this i would be sooo grateful. thanks!

---

I would like to move the ellipse across the x axis one way and then return it as if its bouncing between the two but actually it just moves to the 250 as set in the first conditional as if the second conditional doesn't exist.

Comment: https://editor.p5js.org/aaia/sketches/4mELRE0PH

Comment: `var = circlex = 18` is invalid. This should crash your script immediately. The correct syntax is `var circlex = 18`. Then, what is `x` ? Where is it defined? If it is undefined, then `circlex = circlex - x` will crash too. Open your console (F12 in Chrome), it's telling you all this and all the errors in your code.

Answer (score 0):

When the value of `circlex` is between `250` and `390`, neither of the `if` conditions will be true, so it doesn't update `circlex` and the ellipse gets stuck.

You should have another global variable that specifies the distance that the ellipse should move, and add this to `circlex` unconditionally. The conditions should just be used to change the sign of this variable -- when you get below `250` it becomes positive, and when you get above `390` it switches to negative.

```js
var circlex = 18;
var deltax = 50;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  //background(255);
  framerate = 10;
  //noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  background(255);
  strokeWeight(10);
  //stroke(random(255));
  // for (var circleX = 20; circleX < width; circleX += 40) {
  //fill ((0), random(255), random(255));

  ellipse(circlex, 200, 25, 25);
  if (circlex < 250) {
    deltax = 50;
  } else if (circlex > 390) {
    deltax = - 50;
  }
  circlex += deltax;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```